# How to handle print- and "Save Print output as" browser windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, printing, autoit

1. I have to visit an URL, login using credentials, then select a region name and click on show button so that a recent bill in the HTML page is shown (all this I did using a Selenium script).
2. There is a button <kbd>Print Option</kbd> on that page. When clicked the print popup appears and I need to click <kbd>OK</kbd>. But I am not able to do so using an AutoIt script either.
   [image]
3. When a click on <kbd>OK</kbd> is done the "*Save Print Output As*" window opens where I have to enter the file name and click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
   [image]

These two pop-up windows differ for Firefox and Chrome. How to handle these? I tried using an AutoIt script and by calling it using Runtime .exec(file name) in a Selenium script, but neither works for me.

```
WinWait("Print", "", 5000)

If WinExists("Print", "") Then
    Send("OK{ENTER}")
EndIf

Sleep(5000)
WinWait("Save Print Output As", "", 5000)

If WinExists("Save Print Output As", "") Then
    ControlFocus("Save Print Output As", "", "Edit1")
    Sleep(5000)
    ControlSetText("Save Print Output As", "", "Edit1", "H282")
    Sleep(5000)
    ControlClick("Save Print Output As", "", "Button2")
EndIf
```

Also I need to run the script many times for different regions, but it stops execution after first run.

The Window Info Tool Summary for 'Print' and 'Save as Print Output' pop-up are-

[AutoIt Window Info of Print pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lEmL.jpg)

[AutoIt Window Info of 'Save as Print Output' for the Field to Enter File Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5fsU.jpg)

[AutoIt Window Info of 'Save as Print Output' for the Save Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgWZQ.jpg)

Issue is- selenium code is executed well and when print option is clicked then to handle print window, using .exe file is called and it starts to run in background. but doesn't work. The execution stops once the print window is opened.

[Now the New pop-up is seen , when file name is entered in 'Edit1" for each different file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh5Bd.jpg)

[image: New Offset window is shown]

Comment: `Send("OK{ENTER}")` will not click the *OK* button. Try `ControlClick("Print", "", "OK")`.

Comment: No sir it is not working . please help me with other thing

Comment: `ControlClick` as mentioned works with a test. I am not aware of the `Save Print Output As` dialog and I have no printer setup. If like the `Save As` dialog, then the `Save` button is `Button1` in Firefox 56. Note that timeout with `Win*` functions is seconds so `5000` is about `83` minutes.

Comment: yes sir , its working now. but i am facing the timeout problem now. Even i am using Firefox 56 only Save button is Button2 i got from autoit info window.

Comment: Sometime the involved exe file works fine but later for next run it doesn't work sir. why is this happening ?

Comment: It is difficult to know why failing with the feedback. I posted an answer that may help. Titles and text are case sensitive so ensure it is correct. I would expect a 2nd execution to also work when the 1st works. Ensure that the 1st instance is finished before starting another. Note that `WinExists` can also detect hidden windows, so ensure that these types of windows are not present during testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Opt("TrayIconDebug", True)

; String in filename to replace with an incremented integer.
$sTag = "++1"

; Show custom progress window (True|False).
$bEnableProgress = True

Switch $CMDLINE[0]
    Case 0
        Exit

    Case 1
        If $CMDLINE[1] = '/?' Then
            ; Help message.
            _HelpMsg()
            Exit
        Else
            ; Assign default command line array.
            $aFilenames = $CMDLINE
        EndIf

    Case 2
        ; If not $sTag in the 1st argument, then goto the next case.
        If Not StringInStr($CMDLINE[1], $sTag) Then ContinueCase

        ; If the 2nd argument is not an integer, then goto the next case.
        If Not StringIsInt($CMDLINE[2]) Then ContinueCase

        ; Create array with filenames starting from index 1.
        Global $aFilenames[$CMDLINE[2] + 1]

        $aFilenames[0] = Int($CMDLINE[2])

        ; Find first filepath that does not exist and set an offset.
        $iOffset = 0

        For $i1 = 1 To 1000
            If Not FileExists(StringReplace($CMDLINE[1], $sTag, $i1, -1)) Then
                $iOffset = $i1 - 1
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        Next

        ; Assign the array with filenames, replacing tag with an integer.
        For $i1 = 1 To $aFilenames[0]
            $aFilenames[$i1] = StringReplace($CMDLINE[1], $sTag, $i1 + $iOffset, -1)
        Next

    Case Else
        ; Assign default command line array.
        $aFilenames = $CMDLINE
EndSwitch

If $bEnableProgress Then
    ProgressOn(@ScriptName, 'SaveAs')
EndIf

For $i1 = 1 To $aFilenames[0]
    ; Filename to save as.
    $sSaveAsFilename = $aFilenames[$i1]

    ; Print window.
    $hPrint = WinWait("Print")
    ControlClick($hPrint, "", "OK")

    ; Progress window.
    $hProgress = WinWait("Printing")

    ; Save As window.
    $hSaveAs = WinWait("Save Print Output As")

    Do
        Sleep(500)
        ControlSetText($hSaveAs, "", "Edit1", $sSaveAsFilename)
    Until ControlGetText($hSaveAs, "", "Edit1") = $sSaveAsFilename

    Sleep(500)

    If $bEnableProgress Then
        ProgressSet(100 / $aFilenames[0] * $i1, $sSaveAsFilename)
    EndIf

    ControlClick($hSaveAs, "", "Button2")
    AdlibRegister("_ConfirmSaveAs")
    WinWaitClose($hSaveAs)
    AdlibUnRegister("_ConfirmSaveAs")

    ; Wait for the progress window to close.
    WinWaitClose($hProgress)
Next

If $bEnableProgress Then ProgressOff()

Exit

Func _ConfirmSaveAs()
    ; Handle possible msgbox to confirm overwrite.
    If WinExists("Confirm Save As") Then
        ControlClick("Confirm Save As", "", "&Yes")
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _HelpMsg()
    ; Help message.
    MsgBox(0, @ScriptName, _
     "Automates the standard print dialog from a web browser." & @CRLF & _
     @CRLF & _
     "Syntax:" & @CRLF & _
     "  " & @ScriptName & " filepath [filepath] ..." & @CRLF & _
     "  " & @ScriptName & " filepath integer" & @CRLF & _
     @CRLF & _
     "1st syntax can pass 1 or more filepath arguments." & @CRLF & _
     @CRLF & _
     "2nd syntax replaces the tag " & $sTag & " from right side of the " & _
     "1st argument with an incremented integer (starting from 1). " & _
     "Example: test" & $sTag & ".pdf will start with test1.pdf and end " & _
     "with testN.pdf (which N is the integer set by the 2nd argument)." & @CRLF & _
     @CRLF & _
     "Tested with Firefox 63 on Windows 10.")
EndFunc
```

The filename|filepath can be passed as arguments.
If you want to save as 1 filename then use:

```
scriptname.exe "C:\SaveFolder\a.pdf"
```

You can also do many in same execution i.e.:

```
scriptname.exe "C:\SaveFolder\a.pdf" "C:\SaveFolder\b.pdf" ...
```

If you want to increment the filenames with an integer, then i.e.:

```
scriptname.exe "C:\SaveFolder\a++1.pdf" 3
```

which `++1` will be replaced with an integer and will be processed as if it were:

```
scriptname.exe "C:\SaveFolder\a1.pdf" "C:\SaveFolder\a2.pdf" "C:\SaveFolder\a3.pdf"
```

The 1st argument must contain string `++1` and the
2nd argument must be an integer to be recognized
as a base filename to be incremented.

Help Msgbox can be shown by using the `/?` as the only argument.

Many arguments in same execution may not be suitable for control
in your Selenium script though it is an option.

These windows are standard print dialogs so difference
between Chrome and Firefox may be none.
The "Printing" window is not the same if you print from
i.e. Notepad so that window cannot be considered standard.

Set `$sSaveAsFilename` to the value that will be set
into the edit control of "File name:", in the window titled
"Save Print Output As".

`Opt` parameter of `TrayIconDebug` will display the current
line in the system tray while the mouse cursor hovers over
the icon.
So if it stalls, then you can trace if it gets trapped.
This is an optional function call.

This was tested in a Windows 10 Virtual Machine
using Firefox 63.
The windows appear slow
on display which is why `Edit1` is checked for the
correct string before continuing. An alternative
is to use `Opt()` and parameter `WinWaitDelay` at
approximately `1000` to pause after a window shows,
though the script may take longer to complete on average.

I added an `AdlibRegister` function for repetitive
testing and may still be useful as a file name may
unknowingly exist which needs to be handled.

The "Printing" window is waited for primarily,
just to stop the script from closing before the
printing progress is done.
If unwanted, then remove the relevant code.

Comment: Sir , i used the code sent by you.. it is not working sir.. i can see the .exe file running in backround. but through selenium code it works fine till print pop is opened but  "Ok" option is not clicked .

Comment: The Above code doesnt work me.. can anyone suggest me any other solution for this ?? please do help me

Comment: Sir, Please Check added the Window info.. @michael_heath

Comment: Tq sir , it is working fine. But while running in for loop , if i want to Enter Different file name in 'Edit1' i.e 'Save as Print Output'. How the code as to changed?? beacause Now per this code i.e using AdlibRegister, as file name 'H282' already exists , the next file with same name is not downloaded into folder but for loop continuously excutes . Please @michael_heath Sir Help me with this..

Comment: Updated to use arguments. See description just below the script code. If working fine then consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: where this argument should be given sir- scriptname.exe "C:\SaveFolder\a.pdf" ??? @michael_heath

Comment: " scriptname.exe "C:\SaveFolder\a.pdf" "C:\SaveFolder\b.pdf" ..... "        where it should be given in Autoit or selenium script??

Comment: `scriptname.exe` represents the compiled AutoIt executable. You would possibly run it from Selenium script as i.e. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("scriptname.exe \"" + "C:\SaveFolder\a.pdf" + "\"")`. The `"C:\SaveFolder\a.pdf"` could be replaced with a variable so the filepath changes as needed.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AutoIt\\newcode1.exe" + "E:\\BescomRural\\1.pdf" + "E:\\BescomRural\\2.pdf");  If i give as said the exe file is not called at all. again stops at print popup

Comment: You are missing spaces between the command and each argument. Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AutoIt\\newcode1.exe" + " " + "E:\\BescomRural\\1.pdf" + " " + "E:\\BescomRural\\2.pdf")`. Notice inserted `+ " " +`.

Comment: Check your paths. Try adding `MsgBox(0x40000, "$sSaveAsFilename", $sSaveAsFilename)` after line `$sSaveAsFilename = $CMDLINE[$i1]` to confirm the Save Print Output As argument to debug. Suggest only 1 argument and try 2 if 1 is working. Using 2 may block the Selenium script from doing the next print popup.

Comment: That means that 2 arguments is no good as Autoit is waiting for the next print popup that never comes as the Selenium script is waiting for the AutoIt process to finish. Either change Selenium code to work with 2 or more arguments or use just 1 argument with each AutoIt execution..

Comment: No. it was working fine with more than two arguments , but last modified code you sent its working but it shows new pop each time once the file is downloaded. Please view i have modified the question. lastly please help me with this and one more instead of giving hardcoded file name. it is possible to save the N number of files with numbering 1 to n.. because sometimes it may b more than 50 or 60 cant assure the number. please is it possible? Help me with the code

Comment: Added incremental argument handling. Selenium example: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AutoIt\\newcode1.exe" + " " + "E:\\BescomRural\\a++1.pdf" + " " + "2")` to save as `a1.pdf` and `a2.pdf`.

Comment: Thank you sir, it is working fine. but file name entered in 'Edit1' is very fast Sometimes i am not able to see whether the file name is entered and it is also not saved in particular folder. Sir what modification i should do in code. where should i place the delay. ???

Comment: It is fast. The code checks if the set text is correct so you can rest. You could increase the `Sleep(250)` to i.e. `Sleep(1000)` to view the set text. I added a progress window so you can see what it is currently doing while running. Using a full filepath to an existing folder has not failed for me. I cannot fix if it is working correct. If you use just a filename, then it may save to last saved folder or somewhere else, so I suggest an absolute path.

Comment: Facing the problem. using this = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AutoIt\\newcode1.exe" + " " + "E:\\BescomRural\\a++1.pdf" + " " + "2") , if integer argument is given more then 2 it is not working , after saving a1 , a2  pdf file and next time file name it taking the same name a1 , a2 . since it is same name so File is not able to save.what need to be changed? or can we remove the command even if same name file as to be saved? what cmd should be changed for this code. @ michael_heath

Comment: Are you stating that if `a1` and `a2` exists, then save as `a3` and `a4` or whatever the next available name does not exist?

Comment: If Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AutoIt\\newcode1.exe" + " " + "E:\\BescomRural\\a++1.pdf" + " " + "10") , if interger value , instead of 2 if given 10. then it should save a1, a2 , a3.... upto a10 right? but it save only a1 , a2 later it takes same name a1, a2 only , so file doesnt save.

Comment: Updated to use an offset. i.e. 1st run integer 10: `a1...a10`,  2nd run integer 2: `a11...a12`. So it continues increment over many runs. Requires absolute filepath to check if exist else may give an unreliable result.

Comment: Updated the offset window show on window for each save file. it is visible until exe file is killed or exit. Other than that now based on integer value the file name is incremented as i gave 10 .. now file taken a1 to a10. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$check = True
$printClicked = False
$saveClicked = False

While($check)
    If WinExists("Print", "") Then
        Send("{ENTER}")
        $printClicked = True
    EndIf

    If WinExists("Save Print Output As", "") Then
        ControlFocus("Save Print Output As", "", "Edit1")
        Sleep(50)
        ControlSetText("Save Print Output As", "", "Edit1", "H282")
        Sleep(50)
        ControlClick("Save Print Output As", "", "Button2")
        $saveClicked = True
    EndIf
    If($printClicked = True And $saveClicked = True) Then
;~      set the $check here
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
WEnd
```

If this doesn't work it means you are not getting the controls correctly.
Send the output of `Autoit` tool

Comment: I used the above code . In console i got the following Exception=          Timed out waiting for page load.
Command duration or timeout: 60.11 seconds

Comment: Also , I am new to Autoit tool, where do i can find the output of Autoit tool.@John P.

Comment: May need more information like Window Info Tool summary about the 2 windows to adjust the answer. What information your telling about ?? is that Autoit window info table view??  @ michael_heath